# Reporting Engines used with ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, reports

I'm curious what others are using to build the more elaborate reports out of ArcGIS Web API apps?  By elaborate I mean ones that include lots of dynamic charts and tables, multiple maps/data frames with legends on a single page, etc.  Seems like historically Crystal Reports and SQL Reporting Services are mentioned.  What about ReportLab?  Or with the recent improvements in ArcPy in 10.1 is it possibly better to roll something out independent of a reporting engine?

Answer (score 2):

I use ReportLab with ArcGIS Geoprocessing Services. It has a syntax that takes some getting used to but works great at 10.0 and 10.1!  Of your desired functions the only one I am not currently doing is charts - because I have not yet had a requirement to investigate it.

Comment: Great answer. I am also going to integrate ReportLab with ArcGIS.Thanks for the answer : )